# I am Unable to extract data between <!--<tbody> and</tr>-->

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
siteData = notificationData(url = '')

soup = BeautifulSoup(siteData, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.find_all('table').find_all('tr'):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` won't extract tags that are commented out. You could remove these strings prior to loading it in `BeautifulSoup`:

```
siteData = siteData.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
```